# Typing issues when passing zod schema as function argument and using safeParse

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying to make a generic 'parse response' function in a database module designed for interacting with DynamoDB:

```
const parseDynamoResponse = <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(items: Record<string, unknown>[] | undefined, schema: T) => {
    if (!items) return [];
    return items.map((item) => {
        const validatedItem = schema.safeParse(item);
        if (validatedItem.success) {
            return validatedItem.data as z.infer<T>;
        }
        logger().warn("item failed validation", validatedItem);
        return null;
    }).filter(isNotNullOrUndefined);
};
```

I'm trying to follow the implementation [in the docs](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) for using generic type arguments for schemas.
However, even with the suggested typecasting for `return validItem.data as z.infer<T>`, TypeScript and ESLint are still not happy with that particular line:

`ESLint: Unsafe return of type 'any' from function with return type 'TypeOf<T> | null'.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return`

Can someone help me out with what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: With typescript version 5.2.2 and zod 3.22.4 I don't get type error with this function with result inferred as `(z.TypeOf<T> | null)[]`. Which version are you using?

Comment: @MatijaSirk strange, I am on typescript version 5.4.3 and zod 3.22.4  eslint definitely doesn't like it even when I add the return type to the function

Comment: Do you still get this error if you change entire function to just `=> { return []; }`?

Comment: No I don't get the error when changing the function to return just a blank array, so it must be something to do with the typecasting not working